# DLL works for web based apps but not stand window apps

Tags: external-assemblies

I took some of my most used functions and extensions and put them into a DLL so I can include the DLL into any project.  This works fine for web based projects but throws an error on stand-alone apps.  I do an Imports on the assembly name. I can see the functions and methods but when I try to run I get:

{Function Name} is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Any thoughts?

I have wondered if it is because in the dll I’m doing extensions on some strings and some system.web.ui.webcontrols objects.  I didn’t thing this would be a problem because in the dll I’m doing an Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.

Answer (score 0):

If your function extends a function in System.Web.UI then you will need to add a reference to this in your Windows app.

Without seeing the function declaration, is it marked as internal?

Comment: The function is declared public.  I think you may be right and that is similar to what I was already thinking.  Although I have added references in the past, I can not find one for System.Web.  Is this not allowed in a windows app?